# How to implement capitalization in nHibernate?

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, hibernate, syntax

The below MS-SQL update script capitalizes the first letter of a word.
How does this statement look like in nHibernate HQL (criteria also ok) ?

```
UPDATE T_Example  
SET LANG_DE = UPPER(LEFT(LANG_DE, 1)) + RIGHT(LANG_DE, LEN(LANG_DE) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just have to replace left and right with substring, and len with length. 
Looks like this then:

```
UPDATE T_Example  
    SET MT_Lang_DE = upper(substring(MT_Lang_DE, 1, 1)) + substring(lower(MT_Lang_DE), 2, length(MT_Lang_DE)-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

hibernate hql supports also a function called upper()

see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate the value of `LANG_DE` in code and pass the value for the update?

Comment: Sure I can, but I don't want to write the resulting overhead.